# How to mitigate thirst

Tags: prevention, supplement, fasting, dehydration, thirst-thirsty

Ramadan is starting soon, and I wonder what would be the best ways to mitigate thirst during a long period (in this case from dawn till dusk).

EDIT: I was wondering what could be done not to suffer too much from thirst when you can't drink for a long period of time (Ramadan for example)

Is there some food or drink that you could consume beforehand that will help ?

I am more interested in what kind of preparation one can do.

Comment: Thank you for your post, however I was wondering if you could add anymore details to the question. The more details you have the easier it is to supply a focused answer.

Answer (score 1):

If thirst mitigation is your goal, then you should focus on what food and drink you SHOULDN'T take beforehand. This includes anything salty (chips, soups), diuretics (coffee, alcohol), and sugary foods. Avoid those things beforehand and you should be able to forgo thirst a little bit easier in the future.

Comment: Welcome and thank you for your answer! However, we require that answers have some references available, can you provide support for your assertion that doing your recommended items would help mitigate thirst?

Comment: Wouldn't salty foods *help* with thirst, as they would allow the uptake of more fluids?